# unable to handle this request and hang my pc

Tags: php, laravel

I copy a Laravel project in my local server. After changing some configuration like `public\index.php` where `index.php` out of the public folder.

And change this

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
```

and

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Then I browse in my browser like

```
http://localhost/Project_Name/
```

then my pc's ram usages 100% almost and hang my pc.

even I permission my storage folder 777 like `sudo chmod -R 777 storage/*`

I am using Laravel 5.5.*. I don't understand what I am wrong.

Comment: There are very few (if any) use cases to be modifying public/index.php. You need to be more specific with your question. Include specific error messages, steps to reproduce, etc. All the best!

Comment: _changing some configuration_ – and what did you change? _I don't understand what I am wrong._ – If you want others to be able to help you effectively then you need to provide more details as @KurtFriars already outlined. For reference have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @KurtFriars and Ivo Mori I update my question. Please help me

Comment: Help yourself first! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Application can't handle the request. For this reason your system fails to load.

Not noly `index.php` file copied out of the public folder. You have to copied all files out of the public folder. mainly you must copied `.htaccess` files also along with `index.php`. Then run your application and may be your system will not be hang.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and good explanation. But I have already done.